# Variable seems empty for if statement but it isn't empty

Tags: php, html

Variable seems empty for if statement but it cant be empty

Hey guys, I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to make a simple Site where I can login, logout and change my password. The code is all working, but i have some issues with printing error messages to the users.

On the site for changing my password, i have a form with 3 input fields, the first to insert the old password, the second to insert the new and the last one is to confirm the new password.

Code:

```
<form action="changepw.php" method="post">
  <input id="oldPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="oldPassword" placeholder="Aktuelles Passwort" required="">
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Neues Passwort" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" required="">
  <input id="password2" type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" required="">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info c-btn">Passwort wechseln</button>
</form>
```

My PHP code starts with the following:

```
$error = '';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
  changepassword();
}
else {
  header('Location: index.php');
}
```

In the function `changepassword()`, I check if the form is submitted and if yes, i go ahead with the password change. If the input from the `oldPassword` input field doesn't match with the password in the database, the variable `$error` will be set to 'Wrong Password' (This works correctly, I tested it with `echo`).

Later in the HTML, i place this piece of code to print the error message if it isn't empty:

```
<?php
if(!empty($error)){
  echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>$error</div>";
}
?>
```

The Problem is, that `$error` seems to be empty every time, even when i set error message.

The strange thing is, I'm using this approach for the exact same reason in my Login file to check if the password is correct, and its working without any problems.

Comment: Looks like a scope issue, you change the value of $error inside the function but in the global scope it it still empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you are defining a new `$error` variable in the scope of your `changepassword()` function rather than modifying the one you set at the start of your script.

You can use your `$error` variable inside the function by adding `global $error;` to the start of the function so it becomes:

```
function changepassword() {
    global $error;
    // other code here...
}
```

It should be noted that the use of global variables is discouraged so a better solution would be to return the error message from your `changepassword()` function like so:

```
function changepassword() {
    // other code here...
    return $error;
}

// call like this:
$error = changepassword();
```

More information on variable scope is available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: This did it for me! I used the way with the return at the end of the function. Just needed to add `$error = ""` at the beginning of the function, because it prints a notice on the site that $error isn't defined when it gets returned before I submit the form. But now it works, thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

That should be

```
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>".$error."</div>";
```

(watch the quotes and dots around the variable)

Comment: No, you can use variables in double quotes without  the points. If I would use single quotes, it wouldn't work like that, but with double quotes it does.